# ARP requests not passed between instances across the same subnet or connected to the same router

Tags: arp, openstack-neutron

I have a k8s cluster deployed in OpenStack which for communication uses internal network and only the Master nodes have floating IP's in the external network. I am trying to use MetalLB load balancer(not really a load balancer) to whom I have assigned an segment of the external network in OpenStack and I have used a Floating IP assigned to MetalLB controller to provide access to that subnet from outside.  I am trying to use it on L2 which is sending out replies to ARP requests with the MAC address of the node that has won the leader election.
I have disabled port security for all The instances in OS like in [neutron-port-security setting](https://www.packetcoders.io/openstack-neutron-port-security-explained/)
On the elected node of MetalLB or on the controller I should see ARP request using a command like :

```
tcpdump -i eth99 arp and arp[6:2] == 2
```

I know ARP spoofing is disabled but isnt removing port security going to resolve that ?
I have tested in another environment where VMs where hosted in VMware and everything worked.
Thank you!